# PHP variable into body of php mail

Tags: php, variables, phpmailer

I am trying to get the userTime variable into the body of the php mail - but anything I try is just returning empty.

I tried putting it into a session variable and call it with $_SESSION but unfortunately that failed too.

Any suggestions?

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $userTable = $_SESSION['userTable'];
    $userDay = $_SESSION['userDay'];
    $userTime = $_POST['userOption']; 


    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

      $admin_email = $_REQUEST['email'];
      $email = "xxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx";
      $subject = "Booking Confirmation";

      $body = "Hi ".$_POST["name"].",\n\n";
      $body .= "Your booking for ";
      $body .= $userTable;
      $body .= " on ";
      $body .= $userDay;
      $body .= " at ";

      //none of these work
      $body .= $_POST['userOption'];
      $body .= $userTime;
      $body .= $_REQUEST['usertime'];
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      $body .= " has been confirmed.\n\n";
      $body .= "Your unique booking reference is ";
      $body .= $_REQUEST['ranNum'];
      $body .= ".\n\nPlease use this when arriving or in the event of a cancellation.\n\nThanks.";

      mail("$admin_email", "$subject", $body, "From:" . $email);
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Mail sent!");
            window.location.href = "index.php";
            </script>
        <?php
      }
      else  {
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>

    <div align="center">
        <form method="post">
          Area entered:<br>
          <input type="text" name="userarea" id="userarea" value="<?php echo $userTable; ?>" disabled><br>
          Day entered:<br>
          <input type="text" name="userday" id="userday" value="<?php echo $userDay; ?>" disabled><br>
          Time entered:<br>
          <input type="text" name="usertime" id="usertime" value="<?php echo $userTime; ?>" disabled><br>
          Please enter your name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
          Please enter your email address:<br>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
          <!--the random number-->
          <input type="hidden" name="ranNum" id="ranNum" /><br>
          <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="homepageSubmit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
```

Comment: *"If I didn't explain something well, or missed something, let me know and I will try to explain better."* - Post your full code and an [MCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When in doubt, use error reporting and var_dump.

Comment: Sorry - I've edited it now and put in a proper code dump.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and tell us what it returns.

Comment: I don't see a `userOption` named filed in your form

Comment: userOption comes from the form on the page prior to this - so it does fill in the value correctly on the echo command on the html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `disabled` in HTML forms means it isn't sent to the server. Perhaps try `readonly` or hidden and just display the field as text.

You also don't have a `userOption` field in your form.

Comment: thank you - it was the hidden part that failed. The userOption was actually coming from a form that led into this page. Thanks again